# Посоветуйте чистилку для кода

Tags: html, оптимизация-сайтов

Здравствуйте!

Нужна хорошая чистилка для кода HTML, чтобы оставались только теги и контент, а стили и свойства удалялись.

Comment: Там вроде чистилка написано)

Comment: исправился =) лучше чистилка - ctrl+a - delete =)

Comment: Согласен )

Comment: Мне нужно брать описания оборудования с сайтов поставщиков и ставить на свой сайт. Будет быстрее, если код с сайта поставщиков будет чистым.

Answer (score 5):

Обратите внимание на [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/)

> HTML Purifier не только удаляет все вредоносные коды (более известные как XSS) ... он также удостоверится, что ваши документы соответствуют стандартам.

Comment: Спасибо! Сейчас поставлю, попробую.

Answer (score 2):

чистит HTML по заданным regexp паттернам. у программы в качестве параметров пути к 3м файлам (см. ниже). 
**файл с regexp**, состоит из отдельных пар regexp + замена через `";"`. если надо просто удалить то после `";"` ничего добавлять ненадо:

```
\n;
style=\".*\";style="my own style"
class=\".*\";class="my own class"
> *<;><
```

**входной файл**:

```
<html>

 <body style="background-color:yellow;">
 <h2 style="background-color:red;">This is a heading</h2>
 <p class="background-color:green;">This is a paragraph.</p>
 <p>             </p>
 </body>

 </html>
```

**файл с результатом** :

```
<html><body style="my own style"><h2 style="my own style">This is a heading</h2><p class="my own class">This is a paragraph.</p><p></p></body></html>
```

**исходный код java** (если не знаете что с этим делать, google: java запуск приложения), FilterHtml.java:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader ;
import java.io.BufferedWriter ;
import java.io.File ;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException ;
import java.io.FileReader ;
import java.io.FileWriter ;
import java.io.IOException ;
import java.util.Arrays ;
import java.util.HashMap ;
import java.util.Map ;
import java.util.Map.Entry ;

public class FilterHtml
{
    public static void main ( final String[] args )
    {
        if ( null == args || 3 != args.length )
        {
            System.out.println ( Arrays.toString ( args ) ) ;
            usage () ;
        }
        else
        {
            process ( args[0], args[1], args[2] ) ;
        }
    }

    private static void usage ()
    {
        System.out.println ( "Module usage: <module> <input> <output> <pattern>" ) ;
        System.out.println ( "\t" ) ;
        System.out.println ( "\t\t<input> - input file" ) ;
        System.out.println ( "\t\t<output> - output file" ) ;
        System.out.println ( "\t\t<pattern> - pattern file" ) ;
    }

    public static void process ( final String input, final String output, final String filter )
    {
        // create fso
        final File src = new File ( input ) ;
        final File dest = new File ( output ) ;
        final File pattern = new File ( filter ) ;

        // validate input
        if ( src.isFile () && !src.exists () )
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException ( "input file do not exist" ) ;
        }
        if ( dest.exists () )
        {
            if ( dest.isDirectory () )
            {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException ( "output file is a directory" ) ;
            }

            dest.delete () ;
        }
        if ( !pattern.exists () )
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException ( "pattern file do not exist" ) ;
        }
        if ( !pattern.isFile () )
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException ( "pattern file is not a file" ) ;
        }

        // read patterns
        final Map < String, String > patterns = readPatterns ( pattern ) ;
        if ( null == patterns )
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException ( "invalid pattern file" ) ;
        }

        // read input file
        final StringBuilder in = readInput ( src ) ;

        System.out.println ( "--- before ---\n" + in ) ;

        // prepare output
        String out = new String ( in ) ;

        // apply each pattern
        String p, r ;

        for ( final Entry < String, String > e : patterns.entrySet () )
        {
            // get pattern
            p = e.getKey () ;

            // get replacement
            r = e.getValue () ;

            // replace
            out = out.replaceAll ( p, r ) ;
        }

        System.out.println ( "--- after ---\n" + out ) ;

        writeOutput ( dest, out ) ;
    }

    private static void writeOutput ( final File file, final String out )
    {
        try
        {
            final BufferedWriter w = new BufferedWriter ( new FileWriter ( file ) ) ;
            w.write ( out ) ;
            w.close () ;
        }
        catch ( final FileNotFoundException e )
        {
            System.out.println ( "failed write output file: " + e.getLocalizedMessage () ) ;
            e.printStackTrace () ;
        }
        catch ( final IOException e )
        {
            System.out.println ( "failed write output file: " + e.getLocalizedMessage () ) ;
            e.printStackTrace () ;
        }
    }

    private static StringBuilder readInput ( final File src )
    {
        final StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder () ;
        try
        {
            final BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader ( new FileReader ( src ) ) ;
            String line = null ;
            while ( null != (line = r.readLine ()) )
            {
                result.append ( line ).append ( '\n' ) ;
            }
            r.close () ;
        }
        catch ( final FileNotFoundException e )
        {
            System.out.println ( "failed read input file: " + e.getLocalizedMessage () ) ;
            e.printStackTrace () ;
            return null ;
        }
        catch ( final IOException e )
        {
            System.out.println ( "failed read input file: " + e.getLocalizedMessage () ) ;
            e.printStackTrace () ;
            return null ;
        }

        return result ;
    }

    private static Map < String, String > readPatterns ( final File pattern )
    {
        final Map < String, String > patterns = new HashMap < String, String > () ;

        try
        {
            final BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader ( new FileReader ( pattern ) ) ;
            String line = null ;
            while ( null != (line = r.readLine ()) )
            {
                if ( line.isEmpty () || !line.contains ( ";" ) )
                {
                    continue ;
                }
                patterns.put ( line.substring ( 0, line.lastIndexOf ( ';' ) ),
                        line.substring ( line.lastIndexOf ( ';' ) + 1 ) ) ;
            }
            r.close () ;

            return patterns ;
        }
        catch ( final FileNotFoundException e )
        {
            System.out.println ( "failed read pattern file: " + e.getLocalizedMessage () ) ;
            e.printStackTrace () ;
            return null ;
        }
        catch ( final IOException e )
        {
            System.out.println ( "failed read pattern file: " + e.getLocalizedMessage () ) ;
            e.printStackTrace () ;
            return null ;
        }
    }
}
```